# 日本語に違和感: スコア 3 以上の自分の質問に回答した

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

勘違いから来る細かい指摘ですが、[蛍の光](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)バッチの説明文に違和感があります。
下記のように修正するのが適切に感じますが、いかがでしょうか。

修正前: `スコア 3 以上の自分の質問に回答した`
修正後: `自分の質問にスコア 3 以上の回答をした` or `自分の質問への回答がスコア 3 以上を獲得した`

修正前の説明文を読んで、質問のスコアが3以上であれば**自己回答のスコアに関係なく**バッチが授与されると考えました。
しかし実際にバッチを保有しているユーザは、質問のスコアに関係なく**自己回答のスコアが3以上であれば**授与されているように見受けられます。
(具体例としてユーザアカウントを書くのは気が引けたので控えています。必要でしたらコメントをお願いします)

なお[Self-Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)の説明文は、[類似の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20544/how-to-earn-the-self-learner-badge)などを通じて現在は下記の記述となっています。
`Answer your own question with score of 3 or more.`

Comment: 違和感と言うより、この場合誤訳ですね。"{動詞} {目的語} with {なになに}"と言う英語は「{なになに}を持つ{目的語}を{動詞}する」と言う意味にもなりますが、しばしば「{目的語}を{動詞}して{なになに}を得た」と言う意味合いで使われます。「自分の質問に回答をして3以上のスコアを得た」と言うことですね。もちろん「修正後」に示された訳なら、十分意味が伝わっていると思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

当該部分の和訳を「自分の質問にスコア 3 以上の回答をした」にアップデートしました。1週間以内には更新が適用され、新しい訳が表示されるようになると思います :)

<sub>(Transifex の Key: e1cadb5f5787c7fbe67ef7be205b124d)</sub>

Comment: 当該部分の和訳が更新されていることを確認しました。